# Creating sub-group under existing group for tools in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-toolbox

I have created a Python toolbox and a simple SimpleTool with this initialization:

```
class SimpleTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Simple label"
        self.description = "Simple description"
        self.category = "Group1"
```

It is working like expected - the toolbox puts the tool into the *Group1* category. Now I would like to create a sub-group under this Group1 called e.g. *Sub-group1*.

If you create an ordinary toolbox under MyToolboxes, you can create unlimited(?) new sub-groups in sub-groups in sub-groups in that toolbox. But I can see no way how to do it within Python Toolbox.

Is it possible to create sub-groups under a group in Python Toolbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, although I think I have done this in the past, but I found some code that describes it in a [GeoNet thread called Python Toolbox Toolset](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/75524).

The key thing is to:

> embed '\' separators between the toolsets. Here's an example where the
>   two "Export" tools will be in separate toolsets, nested underneath the
>   parent (also on [GitHub](https://github.com/EsriOceans/support/blob/master/pyt-nested-categories/example-toolbox.pyt))

As the [asker commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230035/creating-sub-group-under-existing-group-for-tools-in-python-toolbox/230042#comment357066_230042):

> It really works, so the solution is:
>
> ```
> self.category = "Group1\\Sub-group1"
> ```